# O UL LI perdendo formatação depois que coloquei ela em linha... Porque as "bolinhas" da minha LI sumiram?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu tenho uma lista não ordenada `<ul><li>` que desejo que fique na horizontal, não na vertical, porém quando eu coloquei para ficar em linha com `display: inline-block` as minhas "bolinhas" indicativas sumiram!

Repare que a única coisa que mudei foi para ficar o texto na horizontal, aí a decoração da lista desapareceu, quando a lista fica na vertical a formatação fica correta. Por que isso acontece? Tem como resolver isso com CSS?

```css
.linha li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="linha">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @hugocsi conseguiu resolver seu problema? minha solução ajudo você?

Comment: @RenanOsorio sim sua resposta me atendeu em partes, mas o que realmente acontece é como o Vitor falou a LI por padrão é `display: list-item` que já vem com as bolinhas, quando eu mudei para `inline-block` ela perdeu as bolinhas. Esse era o problema de fato, recriar as bolinhas não era na verdade o problema entende, mas sim saber porque elas sumiram rss

Comment: @hugocsi ahh simm, entendi agora. Eu tinha entendido diferente a pergunta, mas tudo bem. vlw.

Comment: @RenanOsorio de boa meu jovem! Mas deixa a resposta, pois ela pode servir para outras pessoas em situações diferentes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os bullets `<li>` sumiram porque eles são um comportamento restrito apenas ao `display: list-item`, padrão dos componentes `<li>`.

Quando você define o inline-block no CSS acaba sobrescrevendo esse comportamento nativo perdendo os bullets.

Uma alternativa é criar bullets com ::before, como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.linha li {
    display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.linha li::before {
 content: '';
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 5px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="linha">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais fácil

```css
.linha li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="linha">
    <li>&bull; item 1</li>
    <li>&bull; item 2</li>
    <li>&bull; item 3</li>
    <li>&bull; item 4</li>
    <li>&bull; item 5</li>
    <li>&bull; item 6</li>
    <li>&bull; item 7</li>
    <li>&bull; item 8</li>
    <li>&bull;item 9</li>
    <li>&bull; item 10</li>
    <li>&bull; item 11</li>
    <li>&bull; item 12</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
</ul>
```

o problema de usar :before é que aprincipio não funciona no IE7.